# Mysql filter and display entrys that doesn't contain specific words

Tags: mysql

I would like to filter text data in a mysql table and would like to display only entrys that doesn't contain specific words like:

.de, .com, .cn

I tried as example `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EXAMPLE NOT LIKE '%.com%' and NOT LIKE '%.de%';`

But this give me the error that i got a error in my mysql syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong syntax

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name NOT LIKE '%.de%' 
AND column_name NOT LIKE '%.com%' 
AND column_name NOT LIKE '%.cn%';
```

---

If `.com` is the end of a word, you have to replace your `LIKE` with `%.com`

> Ex : `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_name NOT LIKE '%.com';`

**Check how [SQL LIKE operator works](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is working fine, also a bit better for a overview with multiple words

Comment: @Deex happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

This returns an error cause your syntax is incorrect
Try,

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE EXAMPLE NOT LIKE '%.com%' AND '%.de%';
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sadly that example will run into the error message #1292 - Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table
where example
not like '%.com%' and 
example not like '%.de%'
```